# Android - Adapter creating multiple rows instead of one

Tags: android, adapter

I have a `GUI` for the user to add rows after inserting 2 values. A row would be added while displaying the 2 values which the user added. But apparently it is creating more rows than it is supposed to. For example, 1 click can create 5 rows when it is supposed to only create 1.

Next problem is that the adapter overwrites the older values with the newer values instead of creating new rows.

To sum up the problems faced:

1) Adapter creating multiple rows instead of one.

2) Adapter overwriting old rows with new rows.

Any solutions?

main.java

```
public class BillSplitter extends Activity{

ListView list;

Button calculate;
EditText result;
String total;
String name;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.noteList);

    final EditText price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.price);
    final EditText name1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);

    Button btnSimple = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSimple);        

    btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {               
            double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());
            int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
            String namename = "";
            String totaltotal = "";
            namename = name1.getText().toString();


            if(position == 0)
            {
                totalPrice = totalPrice * 1.07;
                roundTwoDecimals(totalPrice);
                total = String.valueOf(totalPrice);
                System.out.println(total);
                //result.setText(total); 
            }
            else
            {
                totalPrice = (totalPrice * 1.1)*1.07;
                roundTwoDecimals(totalPrice);
                total = String.valueOf(totalPrice);                 
                System.out.println(total);
                //result.setText(total); 
            }
            /*noteList.add(0, total);
            System.out.println(total);
            name1.setText("");
            price.setText("");
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();*/
            price.setText("");
            name1.setText("");
            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(main.this, name, total);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }           
    });        

}

void roundTwoDecimals(double d) {
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    twoDForm.format(d);

  }
}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String result;
private String text;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public Adapter(Activity a, String d, String t) {
    activity = a;
    text=d;
    result = t;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {
    return result.length();
}    

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView text;
    public EditText edittext;

}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nametv);;
        holder.edittext=(EditText)vi.findViewById(R.id.result);;
        vi.setTag(holder);

    }
    else

    holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(text);
    holder.edittext.setText(result);
    return vi;
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:gravity="center">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/name"
android:layout_width="125dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Name"
android:maxLength="10"
/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/price"
android:layout_width="80dp" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Price"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
android:maxLength="5"
/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnSimple"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Add"
/>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<ListView
android:id="@+id/noteList"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Read the documentation, the adapter is working as expected. Each view is put into a row. Unlsee you create a Custom Adapter.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Private class DetailBean{
    private String name;
    private double price;
    /// Getter and Setter methods....
    }
```

Now the Activity Changes....

```
public class BillSplitter extends Activity{ 

ListView listView; 

Button calculate; 
EditText result; 
String total; 
String name; 
private ArrayList<DetailBean> list;
private DetailBean entry;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( 
            this, R.array.spinner_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.noteList); 

list = new ArrayList<DetailBean>();
CorrectedAdapter  adapter = new CorrectedAdapter (main.this,list); 
            listView.setAdapter(adapter); 

    final EditText price = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.price); 
    final EditText name1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name); 

    Button btnSimple = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSimple);         

    btnSimple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {                            
            double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(price.getText().toString());             
            int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();             
            String namename = "";             
            String totaltotal = "";   
entry = new  DetailBean();          
            namename = name1.getText().toString();             


            if(position == 0)             
            {             
                totalPrice = totalPrice * 1.07;             
                roundTwoDecimals(totalPrice);             
                total = String.valueOf(totalPrice);             
                System.out.println(total);             
                //result.setText(total);              
            }             
            else             
            {             
                totalPrice = (totalPrice * 1.1)*1.07;             
                roundTwoDecimals(totalPrice);             
                total = String.valueOf(totalPrice);                              
                System.out.println(total);             
                //result.setText(total);              
            }             
            /*noteList.add(0, total);             
            System.out.println(total);             
            name1.setText("");             
            price.setText("");             
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();*/             
            price.setText("");             
            name1.setText("");             
entry.setName(name);
entry.setPrice(total);
list.add(entry);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             
        }                        
    });                     

void roundTwoDecimals(double d) { 
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.##"); 
    twoDForm.format(d); 

  } 
}
```

Now Come the main correction the Adpater......

```
public class CorrectedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {                

private Activity activity;                
private ArrayList<DetailBean> list;
private DetailBean entry;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;                

public Adapter(Activity a,ArrayList<DetailBean> l) {                
    activity = a;                
   list=l;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);                
}                

public int getCount() {                
    return list.length();                
}                    

public Object getItem(int position) {                
    return position;                
}                

public long getItemId(int position) {                
    return position;                
}                

public static class ViewHolder{                
    public TextView text;                
    public EditText edittext;                

}                

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {                
entry = list.get(position);    
View vi=convertView;                
    ViewHolder holder;                
    if(convertView==null){                
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);                
        holder=new ViewHolder();                
        holder.text=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nametv);;                
        holder.edittext=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.result);;                
       convertView setTag(holder);                

    }                
    else               
{ 

    holder=(ViewHolder) convertView getTag();                
}  
  holder.text.setText(entry.getName);                
    holder.edittext.setText(entry.getPrice);                
    return convertView;                
}                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter implementation is wrong. You should have a list of results in your adapter class. You probably need to go through your adapter code again.

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/04/custom-widget-adapters.html

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/07/custom-listview-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

This adapter will not work with Spinner.I am sure about this.If you want that design then 
take one custom Dialog.In custom dialog take listview and then set this adapter to Listview.
This will also popup dialog like spinner.If you interested in this then i can provide you code also by editing this question